# Python - Capture Individaul value result of request

Tags: python

I am new to Python.  I am trying to capture individual values that returned from the request result.

Here is part of my code to send the request:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json_payload)
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
# Perform the request
result = opener.open(request).read()
print result
```

The print result gives me the output below (messy formatting)

```
{"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/Events(Start,End)/$entity","@odata.id":"https://outlook.office365.com
/api/v1.0/Users('user1@domain.com')/Events('AAMkADA1OWVjOTkxLTlmYmEtNDAwMS04YWU3LTNkNYDHE4YjU2OGI1ZABGBBBBBBD_fa49_h8OTJ5eGdjSTEF3BwBOcC
SV9aNzSoXurwI4R0IgBBBBBBBENAABOcCSV9aNzSoXurwI4R0IgAAHn0Cy0AAA=')","@odata.etag":"W/\"TnAklfWjc0qF7q8COEdDTHDAB5+uOdw==\"","Id":"AAMkADA1OWVjO
TkxLTlmYmEtNDAwMS04YWU3LTMHKNDE2YjU2OGI1ZABGAAAAAAD_fa49_h8OTJ5eGdjSTEF3BwBOcCSV9aNzSoXurwI4R0IgCCCCCCCENAABOcCSV9aNzSoXurwI4R0IgAAHn0Cy0AAA="
,"Start":"2016-08-13T15:00:00-07:00","End":"2016-08-13T16:00:00-07:00"}
```

Is there a way that I load the result into json.load and capture individual values for @odata.context, @odata.id, @odata.etag, Id, Start, End?

I tried this, but no luck.

```
data = json.load(result)   
print data["@odata.context"]
```

Comment: Did you try `json.loads`?

Comment: I am using https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events  API

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think he reformatted the JSON to make it easier to read in the question, so he split strings across lines.

Comment: jsonlint.com is a better way to make JSON readable.

Comment: If possible, please provide me some sample code.  Thanks

Comment: @Milacay Just use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`.

Comment: json.loads seems to work.  What is the different between json.loads vs json.load?

Comment: @Milacay,  use load on a file like object, loads is used on a string

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using json loads. load in the background uses the method .read() so if you wanted to use it you must use a file like object like StringIO or file/open

Like this:

```
import urllib2
import json
import base64
test_load = "foo=bar"
user = "test"
pwd = "test"

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request("http://scooterlabs.com/echo.json?%s" % test_load, data=b'data')
auth = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
result = opener.open(request).read()
jsons = json.loads(result)

print("FULL: %s" % result)
print(jsons[u'method'])
print(jsons[u'request'])
```

**Edit:**
It seems as if the comments already answered the question... sorry